# Python Script GetParameterAsText?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

I am writing a python script to be added to a toolbox and I do not know how to call an existing tool to be a parameter.

```
import geocoder  ##geocoding library
import csv       
import arcpy     ##ArcGIS python module
import arcgisscripting
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
gp = arcgisscripting.create()##creating geoproccessing object
env = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
gs = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  ##csv containing thousands of rows to be        reverse geocoded
cc = gp.SearchCursor(gs) ##creating arcpy searccursor to open and read csv
z=0
for add in cc:           ##looping thru all rows in csv
    Company = str(add.Company)
    Address = str(add.Address) 
    City = str(add.City)
    State = str(add.State)
    Zip = str(add.Zip)
    geo = geocoder.google(str([Address,City,State,Zip]))
    addr = geo.latlng       ##returning xy for each row
    print addr
    if addr:
        x = addr[1]
        y = addr[0]
        firstrow = "Company"+","+"Address"+","+"X"+","+"Y"+","+"\n"
        line = str(Company)+','+str(Address)+','+str(x)+','+str(y)+','+'\n' ##line of info for new csv
        z+=1
        with open("Interm.csv", 'ab') as csvfile:  ##creating/opening/closing csv
            if z==1:
                csvfile.write(firstrow)
            else:
                csvfile.write(line)   ##writing line to csv
                print line
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
newpath =  arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)#arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(env, fc, arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3),"","","",arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4))
arcpy.AddField_management(newpath, "Company", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(newpath, "Address", "TEXT")
cursor=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newpath, ["Company","Address", "SHAPE@XY"])
outcsv = "Interm.csv"
curcsv = gp.SearchCursor(outcsv)
for geom in curcsv:
    addr = geom.Address
    comp = geom.Company
    X = float(geom.X)
    Y = float(geom.Y)
    newRow = (str(comp),str(addr),(X,Y))
    cursor.insertRow(newRow)
    print newRow
```

when i add the script to the toolbox and use arcpy.GetParameterAsText for createfeatureclass tool 
[image]
 this is what shows when i set the parameters

then this shows up when I open the script to use

[image]

So what i want to do is have the create feature class tool parameters open in my script tool...

Comment: No sure what you mean by "pop up".  Are you referencing [Setting script tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm).  If so, just match the order of script arcpy.GetParameterAsText with the script tool parameters. For exmaples... env = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), fc=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1), etc.

Comment: yes sorry did not know how to word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know what will be your new path, you could simply define it yourself...

```
import os
...
result = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(env, fc, arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3),"","","",arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4))
if result.status == 4:
    newpath = os.path.join(env,fc)
    arcpy.AddField_management(newpath, "Company", "TEXT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(newpath, "Address", "TEXT")
...
```

Comment: Hard coding "POINT" should work.  I am still unclear what parameters you want to display in the tool's panel.

Comment: yeah hard coding "POINT" works but I would like the option to choose between point, line, polygon because I am planning on making this script be able to generate polylines and polygons from csvs/text files. So for arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) should it be set as a string? or something else?

Comment: yep I had to set it as a String, i kept putting quotes around POINT in the script tool so that was probably my small error why it was not working. Works fine now thanks